# Is this the right verbal form

Tags: grammar

sorry if my English is not very good but I really need to know if this following sentence is correct : "He will be allowed to go to the cinema when he **would have finished** his homework". Or should I use "He will be allowed [...] when he will finish his homework"?

Comment: **I would have finished my homework** if I had had the time. When I would have finished it, is a matter of speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> He will be allowed to go to te cinema, when/once he has finished his homework.